# Install Samba 4 on Opensuse 12.2

Tags: linux, samba, opensuse

Have anybody already installed Samba 4 on Opensuse ?
Please show me how to do, because without that Samba, i cannot to execute CMD command or any script storing on Windows remotely by using winexe ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try the Samba 4 pre-release packages from network:samba:TESTING on the openSUSE Build Service.

http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/network:/samba:/TESTING/

At this time the one-click install link for Samba 4.0.0 is:
http://software.opensuse.org/ymp/network:samba:TESTING/openSUSE_12.2/samba.ymp?base=openSUSE%3A12.2&query=samba

Answer (score 0):

The OpenSUSE site has a step by step guide: http://en.opensuse.org/Samba

Comment: no, it's just for Samba 3.6.7, not version 4. Do you know how to install Samba 4 on Opensuse 12.2 step by step ?